# LinqToXML - Select elements which pass schema validation

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Is there any way to select only elements which pass a schema validation using LinqToXML?

Thanks.

Comment: When you write a linq statement . just place generic tags like if you are selecting .SingleorDefault() then add tags like  .SingleorDefault<schemaname>(). I suggest it will work.

Comment: What do you mean in schemaname ? The XmlSchemaSet variable name?

Comment: xsd name which has been used to create xml.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I didn't get it..

Comment: refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the Validate method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954.aspx, setting the `addSchemaInfo` argument to `true`, then select elements where the method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342577.aspx tells you the element has been successfully validated e.g. `doc.Descendants().Where(el => el.GetSchemaInfo().Validity == System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidity.Valid)`.